# WPF animation slow when the mouse is in the window

Tags: .net, wpf, f#

I'm trying create a moving rectangle (rect). This is the relevant code:

```
let timer = new Threading.DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick.Add(fun _ -> Canvas.SetLeft(rect, Canvas.GetLeft(rect)+0.01) |> ignore)
timer.Start()
```

The problem is that the animation is slower if I move the mouse over the window. If I set the timer's interval:

```
timer.Interval <- TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(30.0)
```

Then the animation doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

1) if you are using f# interactive check you have installed a WFP event loop. F# interactive sets up a winforms eventloop by default, there is some compatibility between the winforms and WFP event loops, but not everything works to correctly. To install the event loop use the following script:

```
#light

// When running inside fsi, this will install a WPF event loop
#if INTERACTIVE

#I "c:/Program Files/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.0";;
#I "C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.0/WPF/";;
#r "presentationcore.dll";;
#r "presentationframework.dll";;
#r "WindowsBase.dll";;

module WPFEventLoop = 
    open System
    open System.Windows
    open System.Windows.Threading
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Settings
    type RunDelegate<'b> = delegate of unit -> 'b 

    let Create() = 
        let app  = 
            try 
                // Ensure the current application exists. This may fail, if it already does.
                let app = new Application() in 
                // Create a dummy window to act as the main window for the application.
                // Because we're in FSI we never want to clean this up.
                new Window() |> ignore; 
                app 
             with :? InvalidOperationException -> Application.Current
        let disp = app.Dispatcher
        let restart = ref false
        { new IEventLoop with
             member x.Run() =   
                 app.Run() |> ignore
                 !restart
             member x.Invoke(f) = 
                 try disp.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send,new RunDelegate<_>(fun () -> box(f ()))) |> unbox
                 with e -> eprintf "\n\n ERROR: %O\n" e; rethrow()
             member x.ScheduleRestart() =   ()
                 //restart := true;
                 //app.Shutdown()
        } 
    let Install() = fsi.EventLoop <-  Create()

WPFEventLoop.Install();;

#endif
```

2) I haven't tested this too well, but I think using an animation story board will give smother more consistent results, rather than using a timer. I think this would look something like (changing the width property haven't worked out how to change the position):

```
#light

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Windows.Shapes
open System.Windows.Media
open System.Windows.Media.Animation


let rect = new Rectangle(Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Height = 20., Width = 20., Name = "myRectangle")

let canvas = 
    let c = new Canvas()
    c.Children.Add(rect) |> ignore
    c

NameScope.SetNameScope(canvas, new NameScope());
canvas.RegisterName(rect.Name, rect)

let window = new Window(Content = canvas)

let nfloat f = new Nullable<float>(f)

let myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(From = nfloat 20.0, To = nfloat 50.0,
                                            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.)),
                                            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever)
let myStoryboard = 
    let sb = new Storyboard()
    sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation)
    sb

Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, rect.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.WidthProperty))

rect.Loaded.Add(fun _ -> myStoryboard.Begin canvas)

let main() =
    let app = new Application()
    app.Run window |> ignore

[<STAThread>]
do main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Because you said that it could be a problem with F# interactive I did the same example in C#. The C# code didn't work either. My problem was that the 0.01 movement per tick is far too low. I thought that 1.0 would be the entire window, so 0.01 would be 1% of the window.

Comment: If I change 0.01 to 1.0 then the animation works! Apparently if you don't set an interval for a timer it runs ticks as fast as possible (so it would still move despite the low 0.01). The WPF event loop is very useful. Until now I reset F# interactive all the time. Thanks for the story board too.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a story board solution because the animation isn't a straight line. I'm trying to create a simulation of planets with gravity to learn more about WPF. Thanks for your help!