# FSI WPF Event Loop

Tags: wpf, f#, fsi

Is the WPF event loop in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393318/wpf-animation-slow-when-the-mouse-is-in-the-window/393545#393545) answer still a good one for FSI (besides `rethrow` which is now `reraise`)? The answer is from 2008 and I'm not sure if there are any "better" implementations around. If not what would one be?

My [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305889/in-f-who-pumps-the-message-queue/5306091#5306091) is that the default implementation is for WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the default is for Winforms, I do use the WpfEventLoop quite a lot, Code is below,

```
#I "c:/Program Files/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.0"
#I "C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.0/WPF/"
#r "PresentationCore.dll"
#r "PresentationFramework.dll"
#r "WindowsBase.dll"

module WPFEventLoop =     
    open System    
    open System.Windows    
    open System.Windows.Threading    
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive    
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Settings    

    type RunDelegate<'b> = delegate of unit -> 'b     
    let Create() =         
        let app  =             
            try                 
                // Ensure the current application exists. This may fail, if it already does.                
                let app = new Application() in                 
                // Create a dummy window to act as the main window for the application.                
                // Because we're in FSI we never want to clean this up.                
                new Window() |> ignore;                 
                app              
            with :? InvalidOperationException -> Application.Current        
        let disp = app.Dispatcher        
        let restart = ref false        
        { new IEventLoop with             
            member x.Run() =                    
                app.Run() |> ignore                 
                !restart             

            member x.Invoke(f) =                  
                try 
                    disp.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send,new RunDelegate<_>(fun () -> box(f ()))) |> unbox                 
                with e -> eprintf "\n\n ERROR: %O\n" e; reraise()             

            member x.ScheduleRestart() =   ()                 
            //restart := true;                 
            //app.Shutdown()        
         }     

    let Install() = fsi.EventLoop <-  Create()

WPFEventLoop.Install()
```

Test code

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls

let window = new Window(Title = "Simple Test", Width = 800., Height = 600.)
window.Show()

let textBox = new TextBox(Text = "F# is fun")
window.Content <- textBox
```

Let me know if this helps.

-Fahad

Comment: cool, and you've never had any issues using this WPF event loop (same as the one I linked to that @Robert provided, and I think used to come with F# samples pre-2.0)? I know sometimes the WinForms event loop can act strangely. And looking at this WPF implementation, some curious things are 1) `ScheduleRestart` is a no-op with some code commented out, 2) `restart` is never really used

Comment: Well, I use it for quick testing with WPF, like once I checked out WPF 3D models for some container load programming. Mostly I go with MVVM pattern so I only have to test the model and provide it to the UI.

Comment: Sometimes like if code tries to set `Window.DialogResult` on a window I'm poking around, I get flooded with `error FS0193: internal error: Application is already running the Dispatcher.` and the window, ui thread, and fsi just dies.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. `Run()` is never called. Does this still work in 2018?